# How to reverse an animation in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some code from another thread on reversing an animation, but I can't get it to work, so I thought I ask again. Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
$('prices').toggle(function(){
    $('#prices').animate({
       height: '+=200px'
    });
}, function(){
    $('#prices').animate({
       height: '+=200px'
       });
     });
});
```

I just need someone to tell me why this isn't working. It does nothing when toggled.

Answer (score 1):

### Syntax error

You have a syntax error on line 2: use `#prices` instead:

```
$(function(){
$('#prices').toggle(function(){
    $('#prices').animate({
       height: '+=200px'
    });
}, function(){
    $('#prices').animate({
       height: '+=200px'
       });
     });
});
```

---

### Deep seated issue: deprecation of `.toggle()` effect in ≥v1.8

However, it should be noted that in later versions of jQuery (v1.8 and v1.9), this feature of the `.toggle()` method [has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). You will need to bind this event to a click handler, and store the state as a variable.

Also, since you are increasing the height by 200px all the time, it makes little sense to use the toggle function anyway ;) unless you mean you want to decrease the height back to 200px after every other click:

```
 $(function () {
    $('#prices').click(function () {
        if($(this).data("toggle") == 1) {
            // Open state
            // The height should decrease when open state is registered
            // Effect: To collapse the open state
            $(this).animate({
                height: '-=200px'
            });      

            // Now set state to collapsed
            $(this).data("toggle", 0);

        } else {
            // Resting/collapsed state
            // The height should increase when resting state is registered
            // Effect: To expand the collapsed state
            $(this).animate({
                height: '+=200px'
            });

            // Now set state to open
            $(this).data("toggle", 1);
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/nuD4R/3/)

Comment: Now the whole div(prices) dissappears? @Terry

Comment: @KyleKoogler This is because this specific feature of toggle has been deprecated as of jQuery v1.8 and more: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: What should I use instead of toggle()? @Terry

Comment: @KyleKoogler Store the toggle state in a variable, or as the data attribute. I have chosen the latter ;) see updated answer.